# BIRT behind a proxy on a Tomcat Server: Sessoin expired

Tags: apache, proxy, tomcat6, birt

i'm trieing to run Eclipse BIRT on a Tomcat6 Server behind a Proxy. This scenario is like this:
I request at a PC a URL like www.webseite.de/client/birt-viewer/.... This PC redirects the URL to another, which is special for one client. On this sever is another Apache with ProxyPass Rules which redirects the request for BIRT like this:

```
ProxyPass /client/birt-viewer http://localhost:8008/client/birt-viewer
ProxyPassReverse /client/birt-viewer http://localhost:8008/client/birt-viewer
```

The next thing i changes in in the server.xml the Part of  to the following

```
 <Host name="localhost/client"  appBase="webapps"
            unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true"
            xmlValidation="false" xmlNamespaceAware="false">
```

Now it is possible to get to the birt-viewer expample, but everytime it determines with the following error message:
"The viewing session is not available or has expired."

What i have to change, that BIRT will run corretly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay i got it. The problem was the cookie. So i added the following line in my http.conf

```
ProxyPassReverseCookiePath /birt-viewer /client/birt-viewer
```

Now it works!